# How to delete an item in an array that is stored in the backend server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sql-server, express

Sorry I'm quite new to coding and I could not delete the item as clicking it would bring me to the  page and error out. I tried to delete the item based on the product id but it doesn't work. When I refreshed the page, the item is still there.

The array in the server looks like that:
[{"id":1,"name":"Apple","price":2,"createdAt":"2022","updatedAt":"2022"},{"id":2,"name":"Orange","price":1,"createdAt":"2022","updatedAt":"2022"}]

```js
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import AddProduct from "./Components/AddProduct";
import SingleProduct from "./Components/SingleProduct";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [openSingle, setOpenSingle] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  const getInitialData = async () => {
    let initialAPICall = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/products`
    );
    setProducts(initialAPICall.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialData();
  }, []);

  const toggleView = (product) => {
    setOpenSingle(!openSingle);
    setCurrentId(product.id);
  };

  const createNewProduct = async (name, price) => {
    let product = {
      name,
      price,
    };
    let response = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/products`,
      product
    );
    let newArray = [...products];
    newArray.push(response.data);
    setProducts(newArray);
  };

  const deleteClick = (id) => {
    var index = products
      .map(function (item) {
        return item.Id;
      })
      .indexOf(id);

    products.splice(index, 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {openSingle ? (
          <div>
            <SingleProduct toggle={toggleView} id={currentId} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h4>Supermarket</h4>
            <h5>Products</h5>
            <div className="container">
              {products && products.length > 0 ? (
                products.map((product) => (
                  <div
                    className="product"
                    key={product.id}
                    onClick={() => toggleView(product)}
                  >
                    <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                    <h5>${product.price}</h5>
                    <button onClick={deleteClick(product.id)}>Delete</button>
                  </div>
                ))
              ) : (
                <p>Error</p>
              )}
            </div>
            <AddProduct addProduct={createNewProduct} />
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My controller.js:

```js
const BaseController = require("./baseController");

class ProductsController extends BaseController {
  constructor(model) {
    super(model);
  }

  async insertOne(req, res) {
    const { name, price } = req.body;
    try {
      const newProduct = await this.model.create({
        updated_at: new Date(),
        created_at: new Date(),
        name: name,
        price: price,
      });
      return res.json(newProduct);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }

  async getOne(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    try {
      const output = await this.model.findByPk(id);
      return res.json(output);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }

  
}

module.exports = ProductsController;
```

How do I delete an item in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will have to create a route on your express server that handles  the deletion of an element in the array.This route uses the 'POST' method to send to the server the name of the item to remove from the array.
The on the server you find will check to see if an item that matches the one sent is present in the array and deletes it. For this you can use forEach  to find the item and remove it from the array.

```
    myArray.forEach((item,index) => {
if(item === itemToDelete){
myArray.splice(index, 1);
})
```

Comment: Sorry. In my routes I have this.  routes() {
    const router = this.express.Router();
    router.delete("/", this.controller.deleteOne.bind(this.controller));
    return router;
  }

Comment: I've added the controller code on top. So I have to splice the array in the controller?

Comment: i didn't have enough characters for what i was going to write i'll put it into another answer :D

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I'm not able to go through all the code but in the first component at in the deleteClick function:

```
const deleteClick = (id) => {
var index = products
  .map(function (item) {
    return item.Id;
  })
  .indexOf(id);

products.splice(index, 1);};
```

you seem be trying to remove the item from the array on the client. The right way would be to call your backend route for removing items on the server side using axios to make the call and sending the id of the item. Since the backend has direct access to your database (the way to remove the item will depend on the database you are using) or array on the server (here the method is similar to what the snipped i took from your code or my first answer) after this operation the your backend should send the updated array of using "res.json"
this new array should then be recieved on the frontend and stored in your state that way changes made to it will be able to be reflected in the UI.